# Question that was deleted as spam doesn't have a clickable title

Tags: support, hyperlinks, spam

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167525) was deleted as spam or offensive.

> [image: deleted as spam]

And its title, which was replaced with the 'This question was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown', is not clickable now. Is it normal behaviour for questions that were deleted as spam or is there a bug?

Comment: I can click that title. You sure that's what's going on?

Comment: I can't click the title on a spam post on Scifi.SE either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgUaw.png

Comment: However, on the site with a diamond, it shows the post without hiding it, including the title, so that's clickable - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaavG.png (which is probably what @Oded is experiencing, as they've got a diamond everywhere).

Comment: @Oded as far as I know mods see unmodified text (like it was before closed as spam) here, but I see modified text on the title and body of the question.

Comment: Ah, then I'd expect this is by design - there's little reason to be able to click on the title of a spam post.

Comment: @Mithrandir for better understanding I think you could edit my question and add English-speaking image and link from your comment.

Comment: I've replaced the image with an English one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I am sure this is by design:

- This is not the actual title of the question.
- Nobody should want a link to spam post.

If one really wants to see the spam contents, there is a link to revisions. This should be enough.

Comment: *Nobody should want a link to spam post.* ... mods see unmodified and clickable title in this case.

Comment: @alexolut for mods it's different, they need this to track spammers, which they can then destroy. Regular users can't do much with spammers.

Comment: 1. There is a share link. Nobody uses title as a link to share. 2. Title is mostly used for page reload. 3. It should be a link for consistency.

Comment: @Qwertiy I disagree about consistency. Spam isn't ordinary post. Most people don't want to see it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, but they already don't see it. Consistency is "if i click the text where the title is usually placed, the page should be reloaded" - nothing about showing original spam text here - just add a link.